# How can I easily check if a POP3 or SMTP connection is valid with perl / a shell script?

Tags: linux, perl, email, smtp, pop3

I have setup an SSH tunnel to my mail server as follows:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -f me\@mydomain.com -L 63110:mail.mydomain.com:110 -N
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -f me\@mydomain.com -L 63325:mail.mydomain.com:25 -N
```

I can send/receive mail for a while, but after a period of inactivity, my mail client reports that it doesn't get a valid greeting from the mail server.

I have a perl script that checks every minute to make sure that the ssh tunnel is running (via ps) and that the port is open (using IO::Socket::PortState qw(check_ports)), but I would like to check whether or not I get a valid greeting as well.

What would be the best way to do this either in perl or a shell script (running Ubuntu 12.04)?

Comment: no surprise...ssh doesn't speak smtp. smtp servers don't respond until you send something, e.g. an EHLO/HELO greeting.

Comment: my mail client (evolution) is setup to send/receive every 10 minutes I think over the ssh tunnel, which works fine ... for a while

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [autossh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autossh). It automatically monitors and restarts an SSH session with port forwards.

Comment: Re: "after a period of inactivity, my mail client reports that it doesn't get a valid greeting from the mail server": Have you figured out *why* that is? I see that your `ssh` command sends a server-alive message every sixty seconds, so it seems unlikely that the connection between your SSH client and SSH server is dying due to "a period of inactivity". Have you configured your mail client to expect a continuous connection to the mail server, and *that* connection is what's dying?

Comment: @MarcB: Look up [SSH port forwarding](https://www.google.com/search?q=SSH+port+forwarding).

Comment: You know that `SMTP` is for *sending* email, right? Do you mean `IMAP`?

Comment: @ruakh I don't know if I can set my mail client to expect a continuous connection. I think that the connection is timing out, but the only way I have been able to get it going is to restart the tunnel, I would just like to automate that.

Comment: @BenHolness: Re: "I don't know if I can set my mail client to expect a continuous connection": To clarify, I was saying that maybe the *problem* is that your mail client is expecting to continue using the same TCP connection, rather than just opening a new one. But if the only way you've been able to fix it is restarting the tunnel, then that implies that the problem really is that the SSH connection is dying.

Comment: @ruakh yep, hence my question trying to find a simple way via perl/shell to query the mail server and see if it is still connected, seeing as the detecting the port state is not enough.

Answer (score -1):

To answer the question, notwithstanding the setup of the OP, THE tool to use is `swaks` aka the Swiss Army Knife of SMTP. You can get it from here: http://jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/

Typically to test your smtp you would use a command like this: `swaks --server mail.example.com --from ben.holness@example.com --to ben.holness@somewhere.example.com`

It will then show you all the dialogue between the smtp client and the server, making it really easy to pinpoint the source of possible problems.